# Missing "Build Action - Protobuf Compiler" for GRPC Tools C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am following the tutorial below
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/grpc-example-in-c-sharp

I am using VS 2022 community edition, and also tested with VS2019 professional. Neither has this option

I installed Grpc.Tools, Grpc.Core, and Google.Protobuf NuGet packages, but I cannot get the proto file to compile with protobuf compiler, there is no such option under Build Actions

Edit: after rebooting VS 2022, I can see `Protobuf` in Buid action, but it is not building the service file when I buildl the project, eventhough th eproject build is successful. I also dont see Grpc stub classed under it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just follow official microsoft docs "gRPC services with C#" not random

Answer (score -1):

That tutorial is quite old. However in following the steps myself I do not see the same problems as you.

Things to note:

- you should be using the newer .NET gRPC implementation (grpc-dotnet) not the legacy implementation based on the c-core library that the above tutorial uses. That implementation is now in maintenance.
- you should follow the Microsoft tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio-code